# Bigquery pricing/customer support?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a lot of our queries timing out / failing with no reasons provided. I've raised a ticket on the official forum: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/issues/detail?id=22 with no response.

The team here is more active than on the official bigquery forum so I am posting it here too.

How are we charged in such situations? Are we paying for queries that timeout/fail with no explanation? I get error on queries saying "Too many concurrent queries" yet the queries run for a few hours. Does bigquery charge for those queries that shouldnt have run in the first place? Our monthly bills are in a few thousands now, but we have no details on the breakdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery does not charge for any job that returns an error. Only jobs that report success (there is an empty `statistics.errorResult` field) are candidates for billing. We'll look into the issue you brought up.

If have long-running queries, you also may be better off using batch priority queries, since they will be queued and will not hit the "Too many concurrent queries" errors.

Comment: I have used batch queries. The queries are "running for 6-8 hours" before they give a too many concurrent queries error or simply try again later error. I can provide job ids if that would help. 

I've gotten in touch with the sales team to see if the Reserved Pricing might be a solution for us(?). Is there anything else we could do to have a faster turn around for answers? We are approaching our deadline to go live soon.

Comment: Job IDs would help. Have you contacted cloud support?

Comment: Here are a few: :job_iWREhv3FP1pTTS-crvt1qRO_QDo, job_ZKIzq5QSZbmssWd22rYwMoBg_pA, job_Cwz0iAcsv4KzXaFaVjQQeajz_yk, job_OgBy4iUGnWKorJNvW0mjNGMys88. There are about 100 or so after this id that have all failed with "Unexpected. Please try again." I haven't contacted cloud support. I'll do that tomorrow. Honestly you are the only person who is easily accessible for answers and quick to respond.

Comment: I took a look at the statistics for the first query; while the query only reads 75 GB, it ends up processing nearly 4TB of data (is it possible you have a join explosion?). In 43 minutes of execution, it consumed 69 hours of CPU time and 341 hours of IO time (mostly reading and writing intermediate stages). It might be worthwhile investigating what you're query is doing and whether there is a more straightforward way to get your results. The easiest way is probably to contact a cloud support representative; they sit across the room from the BigQuery engineers.

Comment: Just an FYI ... it looks like someone from Google reached about about your rate of submission of batch queries exceeding our expectations. I think there was a combination of high rate and long-running queries. If you can respond to that support case, someone may be able to help.

Comment: Yes, practically the entire team came in to help us out. Incredible, incredible support at Bigquery. They are looking into the queries to see what is going wrong.